# Using map and reduce?

Tags: python, reduce

I wrote a function mean_normal(n, m, sd) that computes the mean of n randomly selected values taken from a normal distribution with mean m and standard deviation sd. I want to use map and normalvariate to generate the sequence and use reduce to compute the mean, however i'm not sure the syntax on how to do that. Here is what I have so far:

```
from random import normalvariate

average = lambda L: sum(L)/len(L)

mean_normal = lambda n, m, sd: average([normalvariate(m, sd) for i in   range(n)])
print(mean_normal(10, 5, 2))
```

I know generally I need something like list(map(lambda i: ..., range(n)) but I'm not quite sure thats right.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use `lambda`, `map`, and `reduce` for this?

Comment: What is this doing that is unexpected? What is the actual question?

Comment: After going through the [on-line tutorials](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php), you're not clear on the syntax?

Comment: @chrischrischris: the point of you question is probably unclear to some people (I guess, "how to use map to produce a sequence of given length from a side effect?"). Maybe if you try to formulate it more exactly, and think of a better title, you'll get rid of the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For educational purposes:

```
>>> mean_normal2 = lambda n, m, sd: average(map(lambda _: normalvariate(m, sd), range(n)))
>>> mean_normal2(10, 5, 2)
4.749961072139493
```

The trick is to ignore the argument of the lambda. However, you would be better off using something like the `repeatfunc` recipe from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools):

```
def repeatfunc(func, times=None, *args):
    """Repeat calls to func with specified arguments.

    Example:  repeatfunc(random.random)
    """
    if times is None:
        return starmap(func, repeat(args))
    return starmap(func, repeat(args, times))
```

I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! this was a helpful example